# (VB) Passing a textbox value with a Url.Action via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

In VB, I am working on an MVC project.  I have a text box to enter some search criteria, and a button next to it that upon pressing will submit the value of the text box.  Html Snippet:

```
<input type="text" id="mySearchField" /> 
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Movies", New   RouteValueDictionary(New With {.searchCriteria = document.getElementById('mySearchField') }))'">Search</button>
```

My question revolves around the final part:

```
 New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.searchCriteria = document.getElementById('mySearchField') }))'"
```

The code above does not work or compile, but this is my general idea of what I am attemping to do.

I want to pass the value of the text box along into the Movies/Search function, however I am at a loss as to how to format the line to mix the html, asp, and javascript all at once.

My VB Function for clarity:

```
    Function Search(searchCriteria As String) As ActionResult

        Return View()
    End Function
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty close.  This has jQuery as a prerequisite.  To make this maintainable (you can do this, or not), I'd use NewtonSoft.Json to serialize the URL to Javascript properly, and url-encode the text box value.

```
<input type="text" id="mySearchField" /> 
<button id=myButton>Search</button>

<script>
     var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Search", "Movies"))';
     $("#myButton").click(function(){
         location.href = url + '?searchCriteria=' + $("#mySearchField").val()
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you codenoir for the response. I am sorry for the delay. I still have not gotten a chance to test this, but I wanted to express my appreciation in the mean time.

Comment: Finally got a chance to test, and it works perfectly! Once jQuery is added, this works like a charm. Thank you!